# How to convert single array value from mix to key index?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

I am stuck

```
0 => [["LINKS","DESCRIPTION"],["Sialkot-to-Karachi","this is trip through sialkot to Karachi."],["Karachi-to-Sialkot","this is trip through Karachi to sialkot."]]
```

I have this Output of my code.. That is

```html
        $tablep_loop = new WP_Query( $table_data );
$tablep_array = $tablep_loop->posts[0]->post_content;
foreach(array($tablep_array) as $key=> $table){
  echo "{$key} => {$table}";
}
```

Where I want to extract this o/p like this

Any one can help me for this..

Comment: I think you are missing code in your snippet.

Comment: It's not clear what the first array represents. Is it `$tablep_array`? Is it `array($tablep_array)`? Is it `$table`?

Comment: I want to extract it like keys will be LINKS, sailkot -to- karachi etc and values will be DESCRIPTION, this is trip..., this is trip and so on

Comment: $tablep_array and array($table_array ) both are same it does not run when I use foreach without adding array with it

Comment: _I am stuck_ is not a helpful problem description. Show us: current result vs. expected result. Also, show a `var_dump($tablep_array)`. Do you get any error(s)?

Comment: Can you provide the dump of `$tablep_array` and `$tablep_loop`?

Comment: string(157) "[["LINKS","DESCRIPTION"],["Sialkot-to-Karachi","this is trip through sialkot to Karachi."],["Karachi-to-Sialkot","this is trip through Karachi to sialkot."]]" this is the o/p of var_dump($tablep_array) while I cant provide var dump of my query and I dont get any kind of errors here..

Comment: My simple question is that I want to make my O/p that is shown in my post above into key and value format and code is ok, I dont get any error but I am stuck to extract it furthur.

Comment: Is that a JSON string?